# How to use builder pattern when the resulting product requires different input

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Let's say I want to create builders for **ModernCar** and **FlintstonesCar**, but they requires different materials for example

```
class ModernCarBuilder
{
    BuildEngine(Steel);
    BuildDoor(Steel);
    BuildTire(Rubber);
}

class FlintstonesCarBuilder
{
    BuildEngine(Wood);
    BuildDoor(Wood);
    BuildTire(Stone);
}
```

How can I create a common interface between the 2?

One way I can think of is like below, but it seems anti-pattern to me

```
class ModernCarBuilder
{
    ModernCarBuilder(Steel, Rubber); // constructor
    BuildEngine();
    BuildDoor();
    BuildTire();
}

class FlintstonesCarBuilder
{
    FlintstonesCarBuilder(Wood, Stone);
    BuildEngine();
    BuildDoor();
    BuildTire();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with creating interface for common contracts(methods) that are required for a builder to build a car. Then create a base class with dependency of raw Material.

```
public interface IMaterial
{
}

public interface ICarBuilder
{
    void BuildEngine();
    void BuildDoor();
    void BuildTire();
}

public abstract class CarBuilder :ICarBuilder
{
    public CarBuilder(IMaterial material1, IMaterial materia2)
    {
    }

    public abstract void BuildDoor();
    public abstract void BuildEngine();
    public abstract void BuildTire();
}
```

Now you can implement IMaterial to you actual raw material classes.

```
public class Steel : IMaterial
{   
}
public class Rubber : IMaterial
{
}
```

For specific type of car builder you can now implement the class `CarBuilder`.

```
public class ModernCarBuilder : CarBuilder
{
    public ModernCarBuilder(Steel steel, Rubber rubber) : base(steel, rubber)
    {
    }

    public override void BuildDoor()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void BuildEngine()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void BuildTire()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Similarly build as multiple type of car builders. Now you can call any specific type of CarBuilder via common base class reference.

```
//e.g. 
CarBuilder m = new ModernCarBuilder(new Steel(), new Rubber());
m.BuildDoor();
```

Comment: Thank you. The main problem I'm facing is that I'm not able to find a common interface for the materials. Let's say ModernCar takes string as input `ModernCar(string)` while FlintstonesCar takes integer `FlintstonesCar(int)`. Would builder pattern still be applicable in this case?